Probability of visible permutations
A visible permutation $\sigma$ of $[1,2, ...,n]$ has a permutation matrix such that all "1" locations are visible from the origin $(0,0)$.
Two "1" locations are visible if the two lines connecting each one to the origin have different slopes. Equivalently, $a$ and $\sigma (a)$ are coprime for $1\le a \le n$ .
What is the probability of visible permutations?

It is $(c+o(1))^n$ for an explicit $c>0$, as conjectured by Pomerance and proven by Sah-Sawhney: https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06268

A visible permutation has been dubbed coprime permutation in a recent paper of Pomerance ("Coprime permutations", Integers 22, Paper A83, 20 p. (2022)).
Pomerance proved that the density of coprime permutations within $S_n$, the symmetric group on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, is at most $1/2.5^n$ and at least $1/3.73^n$ (at least for all sufficiently large $n$).
It is pointed out in the same paper that the number of coprime permutations in $S_n$ has been studied as early as 1977, in the paper "The combinatorial interpretation of the Jacobi identity from Lie algebra" of D. M. Jackson (J. Combin. Theory, A 23 (1977), 233-256) and has an OEIS page (sequence A005326). As noted by Jackson, this number is the permanent of the $n\times n$ matrix $B$ given by $b_{i,j} = 1$ if $\gcd(i,j)=1$ and by $b_{i,j}=0$ otherwise.
In Section 5, Pomerance conjectures that the density is $1/(c_0+o(1))^n$ as $n \to \infty$, for some constant $c_0 \in [2.5, 3.73]$. He presents a heuristic of McNew which suggests $c_0 = \prod_p \frac{p(p-2)^{1-2/p}}{(p-1)^{2(1-1/p)}}$ where the product is over all primes $p$ (the factor at $p=2$ is interpreted as $2$).
This conjecture of Pomerance was resolved by Sah and Sawhney in "Enumerating coprime permutations" (Mathematika 68, No. 4, 1120-1134 (2022)), with the same $c_0$ as conjectured by McNew.
In fact, they make the $o(1)$ term somewhat explicit: the density is $1/(c_0+f(n))^n$ where $f(n)$ tends to $0$ at least as quickly as $e^{-c \sqrt{\log n \log \log n}}$ for some $c>0$.

So as n goes to infinity, visible permutation is a true needle in a haystack.
